# Why is Bootstrap Span class not showing up

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup. The span6 or any span class is not found. Why?

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AppName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AppName)
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HarmonyTarget)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HarmonyTarget)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know about any `span6` class on bootstrap .. make clear your issue

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: http://phatness.com/2012/02/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-style-rows/

Comment: ver 3.2 and the many web pages show the span classes

Comment: spanX is part of Bootstrap 2 not Bootstrap 3. Read their docs GetBootstrap.com to learn how to use the grid system. Many web pages use older versions of Bootstrap, you don't go by "many web pages" you go by the documentation for the version you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 introduced backwards-incompatible changes to the grid system. The `span*` classes only work in Bootstrap 2. In version 3+, you use the responsive `col-xs-*`, `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*`, and `col-lg-*` classes. For more information and examples, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid